# Algorithm that partitions landscape into connected components classified as hillsides and valleys

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I am considering the following problem:

Given an nxm array h that contains height data for given points in the plane. Does there exist an algorithm that partitions the points in the plane to connected areas that one could classify by their height profile, i.e. does a point belong to a hillside or a valley?

I completely understand that this question does not have a unique answer as there is no hard definition of a hillside or a valley but I think roughly speaking any human would be able to make such a decision and I wonder if there is an algorithm that does anything close to it?

Comment: Local minima should be valleys and local maxima hillsides. Starting from these point I would kind of flood the rest and decide if the belong to a hillside or a valley.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the points, and compute the slope between the current point and the next point. Then, iterate over these slopes, and find all points of inflection. To do this-  compute a new "slope'" / change between each pair of adjacent slopes (like we did with the points themselves), and mark the ones that change the current sign (positive/negative). The slope shared between the sign change contains our POI, so one endpoint is a hill, the other a valley. Just look at the sign of the slope' to figure out which (positive is a valley, since the slope is increasing / curving upwards, negative is a hill).

Comment: @Stef left-to-right. I'm treating this as a continuous mathematical function where we're restricted to a discrete set of sample points.

Comment: Then this won't work if a river is parallel to the x-axis, because the slope will be on the wrong direction?